# Including parameter entry UI in a BIRT report

Tags: birt

Is it possible to include UI (text boxes, combo boxes, radio buttons, etc.) for changing report parameters and rerunning the report in a BIRT report? It's good enough if it only works with HTML version of the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  Answered in this thread:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/245467/